# setprecision applied to old C style code

Tags: c++, vector, filestream, precision, cout

I know that in C++ I can use `setprecision` as follows:

```
streamsize prec = cout.precision();

cout << "Your grade is: " << setprecision(3) << finalGrade << setprecision(prec);
```

How can I adapt this to the following old style code, particularly when writing to a file?

```
for ( int k = 0 ; k < vector.size() ; k++ )
{
   fprintf( myFile, "%i\t%f\t%f\n", k+1, vector[k].x, vector[k].y );

   std::cout << vector[k].x << "\t" << vector[k].y;
}
```

What specifically I am confused about is the order in which `setprecision(3)` and `setprecision(prec)` appear, when there is more than one variable, like in the case of `vector` elements being written to a `file`...

Could somebody please help me understand this?

Thank you,

Comment: Why not use a `fstream` to write instead of `fprintf`? Then your code could be exactly the same.

Comment: `%.3f` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Thank you, but I mean how to apply setprecision(3) and setprecision(prec) to fprintf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not clear from the question that you want the `setprecision` to modify how `fprintf` works; it's only clear from the comments.

**This is impossible** (at least, with the existing C++ standard library).

The `stdio` and `iostreams` systems are separate, mostly independent parts in C++. In addition, the `iostreams` stuff was standardized *after* the `stdio` stuff, so to support having `setprecision` affect `fprintf` would mean changing `fprintf` code, which no one wants to do.

To give an idea on how separate they are, look at [`ios_base::sync_with_stdio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) - a dedicated function to make `fpritnf` and `operator<<` interoperate.

To make your system work, you probably have to replace `fprintf` by `operator<<`. Another way would be adjusting the `fprintf`'s format string, but you would have to add the obscure call to `ios_base::sync_with_stdio` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The way to indicate the number of decimals in `fprintf` is `%.[number]f`; in your case, for 3 decimals the code will be

```
fprintf( myFile, "%i\t%.3f\t%.3f\n", k+1, vector[k].x, vector[k].y );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I mean how to apply setprecision(3) and setprecision(prec) to fprintf (not the number of decimals)